# THREE.OBJMTLLoader progress listener

Tags: three.js

Am I able to add progress event listener to THREE.OBJMTLLoader?

I've tried this but it didn't work...

```
var callbackProgress = function( progress, result ) {}
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.callbackProgress = callbackProgress;
loader.load(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the signature has changed this should work :

```
loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load
(
    'thefile.obj',
    'thefile.mtl',
    function ( object )
    {
        // onload ...
        scene.add( object );
        animate();
    },
    function ( progress, result )
    {
        console.log (100 * progress.loaded / progress.total);
    }
);
```